# Passing value from one table to another html page

Tags: html, forms

Below is my code which contains table in a form format. What i want to do is to let user to hover to the price in the table, if it is clicked, it will direct the user to another page which will show the price. For example, if i hover to the price at RM7, when it is clicked, it will direct me to another page which will show me the price clicked is RM7. Please help

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="img/CarRent.ico">
  <title>Kereta Sewa Bajet</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font- 
        awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


  <style>
    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      border-spacing: 0;
      width: 85%;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
    
    th,
    td {
      text-align: center;
      padding: 8px;
    }
    
    td a {
      display: block;
      position: relative
    }
    
    td a:hover {
      background: #808080;
      color: white
    }
    
    body,
    html {
      height: 100%;
      line-height: 1.8;
    }
    
    .w3-bar .w3-button {
      padding: 16px;
    }
    /* Full height image header */
    
    .bgimg-1 {
      background-position: center;
      background-size: cover;
      background-image: url("img/Wallpaper.jpg");
      min-height: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Navbar (sit on top) -->
  <div class="w3-top">
    <div class="w3-bar w3-white w3-card" id="myNavbar">
      <a href="index.php" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-wide">KERETA SEWA BAJET</a>
      <!-- Right-sided navbar links -->
      <div class="w3-right w3-hide-small">
        <a href="login.php" class="w3-bar-item w3-button"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> LOGIN</a>
        <a href="menu.php" class="w3-bar-item w3-button"><img src="img/myr.png" style="width:25px;height:25px;"> PACKAGE PRICES</a>
        <a href="#contact" class="w3-bar-item w3-button"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> 
         CONTACT</a>
        <a href="aboutus.php" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">ABOUT US</a>
      </div>

      <!-- Hide right-floated links on small screens and replace them with a menu icon -->
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-right w3-hide-large w3-hide- 
      medium" onclick="w3_open()">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Sidebar on small screens when clicking the menu icon -->
  <nav class="w3-sidebar w3-bar-block w3-black w3-card w3-animate-left w3-hide-medium w3-hide- 
      large" style="display:none" id="mySidebar">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="w3_close()" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-large w3- 
       padding-16">Close ×</a>
    <a href="login.php" onclick="w3_close()" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">LOGIN</a>
    <a href="menu.php" onclick="w3_close()" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">PACKAGE PRICES</a>
    <a href="#contact" onclick="w3_close()" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">CONTACT</a>
    <a href="aboutus.php" onclick="w3_close()" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">ABOUT US</a>
  </nav>

  <script>
    // Toggle between showing and hiding the sidebar when clicking the menu icon
    var mySidebar = document.getElementById("mySidebar");

    function w3_open() {
      if (mySidebar.style.display === 'block') {
        mySidebar.style.display = 'none';
      } else {
        mySidebar.style.display = 'block';
      }
    }

    // Close the sidebar with the close button
    function w3_close() {
      mySidebar.style.display = "none";
    }
  </script>

  <!-- Car & Prices Menu -->
  <\br>
    <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
      <pre><center>
  <p style="margin-bottom: -3%; font-size:20px">Choose Your Package</p>
  <form method="post" action="a1.php">
  <table>
   <tr> <!--row 1-->
    <th>Car/Time</th> 
    <th>1 Hour</th>  
    <th>1 Day</th> 
    <th>3 Days</th> 
    <th>1 Week</th>
   </tr>
   <tr> <!--row 2-->
    <td>VIVA ELITE</td> 
    <td><a style="text-decoration:none">RM 6</a></td> 
    <td><a style="text-decoration:none" >RM 100</a></td> 
    <td><a style="text-decoration:none" >RM 300</a></td> 
    <td><a style="text-decoration:none" >RM 550</a></td>
   </tr>
   <tr> <!--row 3-->
    <td>AXIA</td> 
    <td><a style="text-decoration:none" >RM 7</a></td> 
    <td><a style="text-decoration:none" >RM 120</a></td> 
    <td><a style="text-decoration:none" >RM 320</a></td> 
    <td><a style="text-decoration:none" >RM 600</a></td>
   </tr>
   <tr><!--row 4-->
    <td>MYVI 1.3</td> 
    <td><a style="text-decoration:none" >RM 8</a></td> 
    <td><a style="text-decoration:none" >RM 130</a></td> 
    <td><a style="text-decoration:none" >RM 370</a></td> 
    <td><a style="text-decoration:none" >RM 700</a></td>
   </tr>
   <tr><!--row 5-->
    <td>MYVI SE 1.5</td> 
    <td>-</td> 
    <td><a style="text-decoration:none" >RM 140</a></td> 
    <td><a style="text-decoration:none" >RM 390</a></td> 
    <td><a style="text-decoration:none" >RM 750</a></td>
   </tr>
   <tr><!--row 6-->
    <td>BEZZA 1.3</td> 
    <td>-</td> 
    <td><a style="text-decoration:none" >RM 140</a></td> 
    <td><a style="text-decoration:none" >RM 390</a></td> 
    <td><a style="text-decoration:none" >RM 750</a></td>
   </tr>
   <tr><!--row 7-->
    <td>VIOS</td> 
    <td>-</td> 
    <td><a style="text-decoration:none" >RM 150</a></td> 
    <td><a style="text-decoration:none" >RM 430</a></td> 
    <td><a style="text-decoration:none" >RM 850</a></td>
   </tr>
   <tr><!--row 8-->
    <td>ALZA</td> 
    <td>-</td> 
    <td><a style="text-decoration:none" >RM 180</a></td> 
    <td><a style="text-decoration:none" >RM 500</a></td> 
    <td><a style="text-decoration:none" >RM 1000</a></td>
   </tr>
   <tr><!--row 4-->
    <td>EXORA BOLD</td> 
    <td>-</td> 
    <td><a style="text-decoration:none" >RM 250</a></td> 
    <td><a style="text-decoration:none" >RM 700</a></td> 
    <td><a style="text-decoration:none" >RM 1500</a></td>
   </tr>
   </form>
  </table>
      </div></pre>
      </center>

      <footer class="w3-center w3-black w3-padding-32">
        <img src="img/BudgetLOGO.PNG" alt="" style="width:85px;height:25px;>
  <br clear=" all " />
  <p>Powered by <a href="index.php "  class="w3-hover-text-green ">KSB</a></p>
  <img src="img/BudgetLOGO.PNG " alt=" "style="width:80px;height:35px;>
      </footer>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I go through your code. You can pass the amount in jquery onclick.

Comment: @SivaGanesh can you please show me how you do it? i am already confused. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How are you getting your prices? If they are static and you just wish to pass them you can append the price to a query string on the end of the url

```
<a href="yourdomain.com/the-page-with-the-other-table/?price=RM7">RM7</a>
```

Then, your the-page-with-the-other-table page will have some JS to grab that string when queried -- You can wrap it in a self executing function which will update a field/table/whatever you like

```
(function getQueryVariable(variable)
{
       var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
       var vars = query.split("&");
       for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
               var pair = vars[i].split("=");
               if(pair[0] == variable){
                    document.querySelector('your-element').textContent = pair[1];
                    return;
                }
       }
       return(false);
}('price');
```

Amended from here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-variables/

Comment: thanks. So, after grabbing it, how do i print out  the variable in a form?

Comment: @WinsonLee How do you mean?

Comment: Say the field in the form you wish to update in an input with an id of 'price' you would update the field's value instead of updating the `textContent` attribute. So `document.querySelector('your-element').textContent = pair[1]` would become `document.querySelector('#price').value = pair[1]` That would update the value of the price field so it was present when the form was submitted.